# i am adding page-scroller-loader like a horizontal line and top scroll button to going on top of website with help of javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

When page-scroller-loader works, top scroll button stop working and when top scroll button works page-scroller-loader don't work.

Here javascript code below:

```
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
    window.onscroll = function () { myFunction() };
    
    function myFunction() {
        var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
        document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
    }
    
    
    // =================Top button========
    
    
    //Get the button
    var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    
    // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
    window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction() };
    
    function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
            mybutton.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            mybutton.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    
    // When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
    function topFunction() {
        document.body.scrollTop = 0;
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    }
        // ==================================Top Button End=====================
```

**[image: In image here top button is working only. Page-scroll-loader is not working]**

**[image: Here when i comment line this line window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction() }; from javascript file so, page-scroller-loader starts work but top button doesn't work]**

Comment: Check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_scroll_indicator. Does this help you?

Comment: I have checked but this is not working.